# Does a date range contain two specfic days

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm using moment.js and am trying to figure out if a supplied date range includes at least a full week where the definition of a week is that it includes a monday to a following sunday.

For example. If a date range includes Wednesday to Wednesday, I need to return `false`, as that does not have a monday to sunday sample.

However a Thursday to the following Monday would be fine as it includes a complete Monday -> Sunday cycle.

I have a simple date object

```
Object {
    start: "2014-03-31T13:00:00.000Z", 
    end: "2014-04-09T13:59:59.999Z"
}
```

but am not really sure where to even start with this one.

The project is using moment.js, but if there is an easier solution using straight javascript date objects, I'm fine with either.

Comment: You have to write logic for that. In my experience moments only helps with date related functions and manipulations. You will have to figure out ur algo for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without moment.js this could be an idea:

```
//assuming you have an object like
// { start: [a date object], end: [a date object] }
// create a range (getDates.call([the assumend object]);
function getDates() {
     var dates = [{date: this.start, day: this.start.getDay()}]
        ,current = new Date(this.start);
    while (current < this.end) {
      var next = new Date(current.setDate(current.getDate()+1));
      dates.push( {date: current, day: current.getDay()} );
      current = next;
    }
    return dates;
}

// assuming you have a range, check if the range 
// contains a full week 
// (containsFullweek.call([the range]))
function containsFullweek() {
    return this.length>6 &&
           this.filter(
              function (v) { return v.day == 0 || v.day == 1})
                .length>=2;
}

// the sunday after a monday modification
function containsFullweek() {
  var mondays = this.range.filter(function (v) { return v.day == 1; })
     ,nextsundays = this.range.filter(
         function(v) {return v.day==0 && v.date>this[0].date}, mondays);
   return nextsundays.length>0;
}
```

Worked out in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/032z7aLz/)

In words: create an array [range] of objects containing all dates from a start date up to and including the end date, each object within the array storing the date and the weekday of that date. Check if the range contains a full week by checking if there are at least seven dates in the [range] and (redundant) if the range contains the days sunday (0) or monday (1).

Comment: thanks @kooilnc, yours looks good, mine is a bit different as I needed to ensure that a week is monday then sunday, not including monday AND sunday. As you can have Friday to Tuesday which includes a monday and a sunday, but not in the correct order of a week. I'm about to post my own answer, but I'm sure you could optimize it and I'll give you the win.

Comment: Hi @pedalpete, that's a double filter. See the modification, and the modified jsfiddle

Comment: Ah, so it is. My appologies. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. I check that a monday occurs before a sunday and return false if it doesn't

```
  // check that a valid week range has been provided for showing Daily Profile
    function validWeekRange(){
        var day = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
        var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((new Date($scope.date.start).getTime() - new Date($scope.date.end).getTime())/(day)));
        if(diffDays >= 13){
            return $scope.validWeek=true; 

        }
        //if we got here, this date range is possibly invalid
        var mondayToSunday=[];
        var checkDate = new Date();
        var startDate = new Date($scope.date.start).getDate();
        //run through each day. the monday comes first, so if a monday is not in Monday to sunday, don't add the sunday. 
        for(var i=0; i<diffDays; i++){
            checkDate.setDate(startDate+1);
            if(checkDate.getDay()===1){
                mondayToSunday.push(i);   
            }
            if(checkDate.getDay()===0 && mondayToSunday.length>0){
                mondayToSunday.push(i);
            }                   
        }
       $scope.validWeek = !mondayToSunday.length <= 1;
    }
```